# Entity Framework - Entity always filtered implicitly

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a typical table which now has a new property named `Inactive`. The name is self-explanatory, the records that are marked as `Inactive` should not be visible.

Then I have several code that access this `DbSet` entity, and of corse the typical approach would be to manually filter everywhere `Inactive == false`

So I thought it should be possible to filter it by default and when I don't want this behaviour I would explicitly apply my filtering condition on that column.

Can you help on that?

Thanks

Comment: add a field to your dbcontext like `tableActives = table.Where(x=>!x.Incative)` and then use `tableActives` where you want to do the filtering

Comment: You can probably use the [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/) Nuget package.